# How does a developer reset CLLocationManager authorization status for Mac Catalyst apps?

Tags: core-location, cllocationmanager, mac-catalyst

### I would like to reset Location Permissions during development of a Mac Catalyst app.

When working on iOS simulators, one only need "reset simulator."
On an iOS device, it's possible to "Reset Location & Priacy" from the Settings app.

I've looked in the Security & Privacy pane of System Preferences on macOS 10.15.7, but my app doesn't show there.

I've also used `tccutil` to try and reset - `tccutil reset ALL my.bundle.id`. This presents a success message "Successfully reset All approval status for my.bundle.id," but subsequent launches of the Mac Catalyst app have `CLLocationManager` with an `.approved` status.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found is to create a new User on the computer. I've put the .app in the Shared folder so that it can quickly be started from the other session.